# How to allow a read-only login/user with execute permissions to run stored procedure that drops and creates databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-security

I have a SQL Server 2016 instance with a **Tools** database. The **Tools** database has a **RestoreDBFromPath** procedure that can restore a backup file to a database on the server. If the database already exists it drops the database and restores the backup. While restoring the backup it also writes some data to some logging tables on the **Tools** databases.

Example Call:

```
USE [Tools]
GO

DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX), @DBName NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Path = 'C:\Backups\Mybackup.bak'
SET @DBName = 'RestoredDB'


EXECUTE [dbo].[LoadDatabaseFromBackup] @Path, @DBName
GO
```

Right now, I have a 2 logins on the server:

- Admin - sysadmin that can do anything
- ReadOnlyUser - Can view any database/definition on the server as well as connect to any database

The **Tools** database has 1 user (Admin can connect since its a sysadmin):

- ReadOnlyUser - can view any definition, read from any table, and execute **RestoreDBFromPath** on the **Tools** database.

If I execute the **RestoreDBFromPath** procedure while logged in as Admin, then everything works fine. However trying to run it as ReadOnlyUser causes it to fail since that user can't write to tables on **Tools** and it especially can't drop/create/restore databases on the server.

What is a simple and secure way that I can allow ReadOnlyUser to execute **RestoreDBFromPath** successfully just like Admin can?

Things I've Tried:

- Changing the SP signature to `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RestoreDBFromPath @Path NVARCHAR(MAX), @DBName NVARCHAR(MAX) WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`
- creating a user without login on the **Tools** database with full permissions and setting the SP to execute as them

Things I've tried, but may not have done correctly:

- Made a certificate on **Tools** via a password, created a user from that certificate, given the user full permissions, signed the **RestoreDBFromPath** SP with the certificate

Things I've heard about but found no good examples:

- Using an Asymetric Key

Comment: Why in the world do you want to allow a user that has readonly access the power to drop existing databases and overwrite them? That screams of horrible process design.

Comment: There are lots of constraints inside the RestoreDBFromPath procedure that keeps things "safe". This procedure allows users to restore a database in a controlled manner, rather than giving a user full permissions to wreck havoc by manually doing a restore.

Comment: isn't this what `execute as owner` is for? Now it may not work when the owner is `dbo` (since that user usually doesn't have drop/create db privs), but if you have the owner as a user who is part of `dbcreator` role, seems like it should work how you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ReadOnlyUser to execute the stored procedure on the Tools database,

- they need to have execute permission on the stored procedure

For dropping and creating any database on the server, the ReadOnlyUser needs to be a dbCreator on the server. (the drawback is that they can drop any database).

In order to write to the log tables in the Tools database, grant write permission to the ReadOnlyUser on the log tables.

Comment: But is there a way that I can give the stored procedure itself permissions or create a dedicated user that has permissions and can only be used inside the procedure?